# webpack 2 "webpack-dev-server"

Tags: javascript, webpack-dev-server, webpack-2, webpack-style-loader

i'm newbie with webpack 2 , my issue is when i run webpack-server (http://localhost:8080/) , webpack not redirect me in the correct page and my css not working too.
i get this page : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3fQXw.png)

my webpack.config.js :

```
 const ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");
var path = require("path");


module.exports = {
    entry : './src/app.js',
    output : {
        path : path.resolve(__dirname,'dist/'),
        filename : 'app.bundle.js'
    },
    module : {
        rules : [
            //{test: /\.css$/, use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract(['style-loader','css-loader'])},
            {test: /\.scss$/, 
            loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                fallback: "style-loader",
                use: ['css-loader','sass-loader'],
                publicPath: "/dist"
            })}
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new ExtractTextPlugin({
            filename: "/dist/app.scss",
            disable: false,
            allChunks: true
        })
    ]
}
```

thank you !

Comment: Do you have just .css files or just .scss files or both?

Comment: just .scss file

Comment: Do you see those files being loaded over the network tab (developer console)? Do you have any error logs?

Comment: nothing in network tab

Comment: but if i open my index.html without server it's wok fine